# access network path from PowerShell running with Administrative Rights

Tags: windows, powershell, networking

I have a *network path* named P:\ and when I run **PowerShell** in standard mode I can access it just fine. But when I run **PowerShell** with *Administrative Rights* it says it can't find a drive named P:

How to access the path?

Comment: Set "EnableLinkedConnections" to a DWORD value of 1 in the registry key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", and restart the system. After applying this policy, creating a mapped drive is linked to both logon sessions. On the other hand, a substitute drive created with subst.exe, or anything else that simply calls `DefineDosDeviceW`, will create the drive only in the current logon session, so the command has to be manually repeated in the linked session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run PowerShell in standard mode, you say: run PowerShell with the current already authenticated credentials and session and context. This includes all drive mappings inside your current session.

When you run PowerShell as Administrator, the first question is: how do you verify that the Credentials are valid? You can't just look at the username and assume that you can re-use the existing session e.g. you have to explicitly check, exactly at this moment, to see that you are a member of the Administrators group. To validate the credentials, PowerShell performs an authentication check, and in turn, gets a new authentication ticket. This new authentication ticket creates the basis of a new context that your new PowerShell session is running from.

Since it's a new session, running under a completely new context, with new authentication ticket, it inherits no mapped drives because the current administrative session hasn't authenticated with any of your mapped drives. Only your other "non-administrative" or "normal" session has authenticated with any of your mapped drives.

This means that your administrative session starts by default without any mapped drives from your previous session, and *it doesn't matter about access or rights*, you simply haven't authenticated with your new authentication ticket. This means that, after launching as Administrator, you will have to manually re-map all your drives, as you will have to re-authenticate all the mappings with your new authentication ticket.

Basically, if you need access to mapped drives inside an administrative session, you will need to remap them.

---

EDIT:

But, as per @ErykSun's comments, @ErykSun brings up the only workaround by setting: [`EnableLinkedConnections`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3035277/mapped-drives-are-not-available-from-an-elevated-prompt-when-uac-is-co). This is a very specific workaround that only works on GPO mapped drives at logon with the right UAC settings.

This "new session" issue is caused because of the new "feature" Microsoft introduced: UAC elevation (aka. stop running everything as Administrator). In order for certain legacy applications to work, Microsoft had to add this registry Key to create a workaround for mapped drives, e.g. most notably if you need to run something off a mapped drive as administrator (it's a poor user experience to run something off a mapped drive and promptly have it crash because it can't find itself or other files it needs).

How it works is pretty clever. On logon, it will create ***two sessions*** at the same time. Your regular non-elevated session, but also an elevated administrative session. At logon, when drive mappings are created, the system creates symbolic link objects that associate the drive letters to the UNC paths.

Note: This is only at logon, and so the caveats are that it only applies to **GPO mapped drives**.

Drives mapped via login scripts won't work because you have already "started" your session, and there is no link. Same with drives manually mapped during your session. Also when the UAC policy is configured to `Prompt for credentials` this won't implicitly create the second administrative session (you assume that the user is not an admin) and so running as administrator will create a new session, with the same above issues.

On that note, you can enable it through GPO:

1. In Local Group Policy Editor, locate the following Group Policy path:

   `Local Computer Policy\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options`
2. Configure the following policy to Prompt for consent:

   **User Account Control:** Behaviour of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode

Or via setting the registry key:

1. Open regedit
2. Locate and then right-click the following registry subkey:

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
3. Select 'New' and click DWORD (32-bit) Value
4. Name it: `EnableLinkedConnections`
5. Right-click `EnableLinkedConnections`, and then click 'Modify'
6. In the 'Value data' box, type `1`, and then click **OK**.
7. Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer